# Node req.body.item exists, but if statement isn't firing

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have a bootstrap form:

```html
  <form action="/users/dashboard" method="POST">
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="input-group">
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <label for="beginDate" class="input-group-text" id="beginDateLabel">From</label>
          </div>
          <input type="date" name="beginDate" id="beginDate" aria-describedby="beginDateLabel">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="input-group">
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <label for="endDate" class="input-group-text" id="endDateLabel">To</label>
          </div>
          <input type="date" name="endDate" id="endDate" aria-describedby="endDateLabel">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="submit">Go</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

On the Node back end, I have an `if` statement looking for those two inputs:

```js
let beginDate = new Date();
beginDate.setMonth(beginDate.getMonth() - 5);
if (req.body.beginDate) {
  const dateArr = req.body.beginDate.split('-');
  beginDate = new Date(parseInt(dateArr[0]),parseInt(dateArr[1]) - 1, 01);
};

let endDate = new Date();
if (req.body.endDate) {
  const dateArr = req.body.endDate.split('-');
  endDate = new Date(parseInt(dateArr[0]),parseInt(dateArr[1] - 1), 01);
};
```

The first `if` statement catches the `req.body.beginDate` just fine, but the second one is skipped entirely, even though that second input definitely has a value. Looking at it in the debugger it shows what I expect, a string of `'2020-03-08'` or whatever the selected date is.

Any idea why that second `if` statement is being ignored?

Comment: Are you sure an error isn't being thrown prior to reaching the second if statement?

Comment: Did you consoled also the req.body.endDate value? I think it is empty.

Comment: I'm wondering if `beginDate = new Date(parseInt(dateArr[0]),parseInt(dateArr[1]) - 1, 01);` is throwing an error.  Just put a `console.log("before endDate", req.body.endDate)` right before the `let end endDate = new Date()` line of code and see if you see that log statement and see what the value of `req.body.endDate` is.

Comment: I don't understand what's happened. All I did was add in the console.logs you guys suggested and suddenly it started working. I changed nothing else. Well, while we're at it, I may as well say that I didn't even need the logs, because like I said in the question, debugging breakpoints showed me those same values.